# How to specify Schema name while using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: spring-data, teradata

I am trying to invoke a parameter less stored procedure using the Spring Annotation @NamedStoredProcedureQuery.

Technology stack is Spring Data JPA with Hibernate, and database is Teradata.

It always fails saying "Procedure not found" because it tries to invoke as

```
   call proc_name()
```

which is bound to fail.

However the right way to call the stored procedure is

```
call schemaName.proc_name()
```

I can't figure out a way to specify the schema name in the Entity that I have created.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name="proc_name",
        procedureName="proc_name",
        resultClasses = { Sc_Refresh.class }
)

@Entity
@Table(schema = "Schema_Name", name = "TEMP_TABLE" )
public class Sc_Refresh {

}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the solution.

In the Repo layer, wherein we are using @Procedure annotation, we should provide the fully qualified name for the procedure. Example,

```
@Repository
public interface Repo  extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long>{

    @Procedure("SCHEMA_NAME.PROC_NAME")
    void explicitlyNamedProcName();

}
```

Comment: What about if the stored proc is inside a Package too? SCHEMA.PACKAGE_NAME.PROC_NAME???

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked for me.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name="procName",
        procedureName="<schema_name>.proc_name"
)
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
...
}
```

Put the schema name before database procedure name in the *procedureName* annotation attribute name. Hope it helps.