# Spring Data JPA : Stored Procedure with Schema Name

Tags: oracle, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data

Please if anyone has experienced calling oracle stored procedure from spring data specifying schema, package and procedure name.
I have the following entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY", schema = "SCHEMA_ENTITY")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "name1",
    procedureName = "packageName.procName",
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "param1", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "return_value", type = BigDecimal.class)
    })})

public class EntityExp {

     @Id
    private Long keyId;
    ...
}
```

Repository :

```
 public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityExp, Long> {

   @Procedure(name = "name1")
   BigDecimal test(@Param("param1") String param1);
}
```

In the service implemetation, after autowiring it, I call the procedure like :

```
BigDecimal returnVal = entityRepository.test(param1);
```

The oracle stored proc definition is :

```
create or replace PACKAGE packageName as
          function procName(param1 IN VARCHAR)
               RETURN NUMBER;
END packageName;
create or replace PACKAGE BODY packageName
        IS
        function procName (param1 IN VARCHAR) 
        RETURN NUMBER
        IS
        BEGIN
        return 1;
        END;
        END;
```

The procedure works fine if I call it using PL/Sql..

And I got the following error :

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'package.procName' must be declared
```

I also tested many configs, like specifying the schema in the procedure:

```
@Procedure(name = "SCHEMA_ENTITY.name1")
BigDecimal test(@Param("param1") String param1);
```

But still fails...

I can't find any example using schema + package + procedureName while calling the stored procedure...

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that understood your issue completely, but I'll try to share some information since I had a related issue recently.

The first item is related to the way you call the stored procedure. It looks like the returned type of the stored procedure is not currently supported by Spring-data. For more info [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/issues/220). However, with `void` it is working fine.

I resolved that by creating a separate `Repository` where I call the procedures which return result through the `entityManager`. An example which illustrates that [link](http://stevenhorvatin.com/2016/09/30/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-spring-boot-using-jpahibernate/).

The second item is about schema name. I believe when you resolve the first item you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808904/how-to-specify-schema-name-while-using-namedstoredprocedurequery/50658015#50658015) question to try to resolve it. In a nutshell, I set the schema name in the `procedureName` annotation attribute name.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name="procName",
        procedureName="<schema_name>.proc_name"
)
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
...
}
```

Hope it helps.